# What does this arguement to sh mean?

Tags: linux

What does -f mean here in this particular line of the script file?

```
#!/bin/sh -f
```

I cant find anything in the man page

Answer (score 1):

It disables pathname expansion.  From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06:

> After field splitting, if set -f is not in effect, each field in the
> resulting command line shall be expanded using the algorithm described
> in Pattern Matching Notation

For example:

```
$ sh -c 'echo *'
a b
$ sh -f -c 'echo *'
*
```

Answer (score 1):

A search for `man sh` leads to e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html:

> The `-a`, `-b`, `-C`, `-e`, `-f`, `-m`, `-n`, `-o` option, `-u`, `-v`, and `-x` options
> are described as part of the *set* utility in *Section 2.14, Special
> Built-In Utilities*.

Then a search for `man set` leads to e.g. https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html:

> `-f`  Disable file name generation (globbing).

This means, the shell will not expand wildcard characters in file names.

The line

```
#!/bin/sh -f
```

sets this option for the shell that executes the shell script.